# sql exception while updating data

Tags: c#, sql

While updating data, I get the following exception:

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

Can anyone help me please?

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select*from Clinic_info", cn);
    SqlCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Clinic_info");
    //ds.Tables["Clinic_info"].Constraints.Add("CL_ID_pk", ds.Tables["Clinic_info"].Columns["CL_ID"], true);

    try
    {
        DataRow row;

        row = ds.Tables["Clinic_info"].Rows.Find(Session["msg"].ToString());
        row.BeginEdit();
        row["CL_Name"] = cl_name.Text;
        row["CL_Desc"] = cl_descri.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure sql table has primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got `select * from Clinic_info` in the code instead of `select*from Clinic_info`. 
And, as [Coder has told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566418/sql-exception-while-updating-data/7566484#7566484), check the table has a primary key. This is the reason behind the exception.